# MySql: joining same table with millions rows

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with millions of rows (SF_COLLECTIONS)

```
ID MEMBERID COLLECTIONID CARDID STATE (D / M)
1  1        1            1      D
2  1        1            2      D
3  2        1            1      M
4  2        1            2      M
5  2        1            3      D
6  1        1            3      M
```

and I have to cross those that have MEMBERID = 1 and STATE = D with those that have MEMBERID = 2 and STATE = M and vice versa

This is my query

```
SELECT 1
    FROM sf_collections AS rac
    INNER JOIN sf_collections AS myrac 
        ON 
        (myrac.cardid = rac.cardid AND 
            (
                (myrac.state = "M" AND rac.state = "D") OR 
                (myrac.state = "D" AND rac.state = "M")
            )
        ) 
    WHERE
    rac.memberid = 1 AND myrac.memberid = 2
    GROUP BY rac.memberid
```

(response time about 4 seconds)

Is this a valid approach or there is a better way to improve performance?

Sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE `sf_collections` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `collectionid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cardid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `state` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `sf_collections_pkey` (`memberid`,`collectionid`,`cardid`,`state`),
 KEY `collectionid` (`collectionid`),
 KEY `memberid` (`memberid`),
 KEY `cardid` (`cardid`),
 KEY `state` (`state`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22627806 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT INTO sf_collections (memberid,collectionid,cardid,state) VALUES
(1,1,1,'D'),
(1,1,2,'D'),
(1,1,3,'M'),
(2,1,1,'M'),
(2,1,2,'M'),
(2,1,3,'D');

SELECT 1
    FROM sf_collections AS rac
    INNER JOIN sf_collections AS myrac 
        ON 
        (myrac.cardid = rac.cardid AND 
            (
                (myrac.state = "M" AND rac.state = "D") OR 
                (myrac.state = "D" AND rac.state = "M")
            )
        ) 
    WHERE
    rac.memberid = 1 AND myrac.memberid = 2
    GROUP BY rac.memberid
```

[and db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sn7q7Bq9PKNYDyCiQQuEJX/0)

Thanks

EDIT: MySql is 5.0 (very old and cannot upgrade this)

Comment: try removing the whole `OR` and run the query.. how long will it take?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: Also, I don't see that `SELECT 1` is going to tell you very much

Comment: @Strawberry SELECT 1 tells me "Ok, there's a match", but it was used only for the purpose of this post, and the group by is to avoid multiple "1" results

Comment: Well without knowing what you're actually after, it's difficult to advise on how to get there.

Comment: @Strawberry You're right and I'm sorry. My goal is to list the matches, but my question is if I used the best approach to join the same table
EDIT: MySql is 5.0 (very old and cannot upgrade this)

Comment: @Strawberry [Here is the db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sn7q7Bq9PKNYDyCiQQuEJX/0)

Comment: Note that `KEY memberid...` is redundant, and why are you using MyISAM and not InnoDB?

Comment: And I still don't believe that this is the result that you're really after

Comment: @Strawberry Could you please explain me why `KEY memberid..` is redundant? Also I'm forced to use MyISAM because I'm in a hosted DB which runs MySql 5.0 and InnoDB is available from 5.5 onwards

Comment: Because it's already covered by your UNIQUE KEY - and other hosts are available. 2005 was a lifetime ago!

Comment: @Strawberry .. therefore the other keys are also redundant .. right?

Comment: No. The index operates in the order its defined. If the first column in the index isn't utilised by the query, MySQL cannot simply skip it and move to the next column in the index. Does that make sense? - It's like the index at the back of a book. The first part of the index is the search term, arranged alphabetically, the second part of the index is the page number. While it's useful and practical to search for the search term in order to find the page number, it's not practical to search for the page number in order to find the search term.

Comment: @Strawberry .. and redundant key memberid could affect performances (and maybe space)? Do you suggest to delete it?

Comment: Yes. Delete it!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `INDEX(cardid)` with `INDEX(cardid, state)`

If practical, don't check for both D->M and M->D; just do one direction.  This will cut in half the effort.

Avoid the `SELECT ... GROUP BY ...` by switching to `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )`.  If there are multiple matching rows, this will speed things up.  If you will eventually be "listing the matches", we may as well see what you want rather than nitpicking over the bad use of `GROUP BY`.  Will you be using a `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Move from MyISAM to InnoDB.  Even in 5.0 it may have been intrinsically faster for this query.

`DROP INDEX(memberid)` since the unique index handles such.

Do you need `id` for anything?  If not, get rid of it and promote the 4-column `UNIQUE` index to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

If `state` is just a flag (0/1), the `INDEX(state)` will probably never be used; drop it.

Comment: Thanks Rick for the answer